# Magnetic dipole moment on a non-planar circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

A simple and useful expression for the magnetic dipole moment $\mathbf m$ of a closed circuit with constant current $I$, around a curve $\gamma$, is$$\mathbf m \equiv IA\mathbf{\hat n}$$

where $A$ is the area of the surface $S$ with boundary $\gamma\equiv\partial S$, and $\mathbf{\hat n}$ the vector normal to $S$. Obviously this is only valid for a "planar circuit", i.e., one where the curve is contained in some plane (normal to $\mathbf{\hat n}$).

Is there a way to generalize this simple expression to an arbitrary closed curve?

I have a couple of ideas:

- The surface $S$ in principle could be anything, but in the expression above it is taken to be the one with minimum area: a plane. So a possible generalisation would be to take $A$ to be the minimum area bounded by the curve $\gamma$, but then the vector $\mathbf{\hat n}$ would be undetermined.
- An alternative could be to project the curve onto the coordinate planes to obtain three planar curves $\gamma_x, \gamma_y, \gamma_z$ with inscribed areas $A_x, A_y, A_z$ respectively. Then the components $n_i$ of $\mathbf{\hat n}$ could be taken to be $n_i=A_i/\sqrt{\sum_jA_j^2}$. With this definition, the components of the vector $\mathbf{\hat n}$ coincide with their actual values for a planar curve. The problem here would be the determination of the effective area $A$, which for the case of a planar curve is just $A=\sqrt{\sum_jA_j^2}$, but that may not be the case for an arbitrary circuit.

Is there a well defined and simple way to do this? One could also use the means of integration to obtain the answer, with $\mathbf{m}=\frac{1}{2}I\int_{\gamma}\mathbf x\times\mathbf t \mathrm ds$, but it would be nice if there was a way to obtain the same results by the means of simple operations on areas instead of a potentially very complex line integral.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to generalize the concept of moments is to start with the definition of *vector potential*:
$$\bf{B} = \rm{curl} \bf{B} \\ \rm{curl}{\bf{A}}=\mu_0 \bf{J}$$

These plus the side condition $\rm{div}\bf{A}=0$ will give you the starting point to generalization: $$\bf{A(r)}= \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int_{V} \frac{\bf{J(r')}}{|\bf{r} - \bf{r}'|} \textrm{dV}'.$$
Next we expand the kernel into a "vector" Taylor series:

$$\frac{1}{|\bf{r} - \bf{r}'|} =\frac{1}{|\bf{r}|} - \sum_{j=1}^{3}r'_j\frac{\partial}{\partial r_j}\big(\frac{1}{r}\big)+
\sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}r'_j r'_i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r_j\partial r_i}\big(\frac{1}{r}\big)+...
\\= \frac{1}{|\bf{r}|} + \frac{\bf{r} \cdot \bf{r}'}{|\bf{r}|^3}+....$$
This can be rearranged as 
$$\bf{A(r)}= \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int_{V} \frac{\bf{J(r')}}{|\bf{r} - \bf{r}'|}
\big( \frac{1}{|\bf{r}|} + \frac{\bf{r} \cdot \bf{r}'}{|\bf{r}|^3}+....
\big) \textrm{dV}' \\
= \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi} \frac{1}{|\bf{r}|} \int_{V} \bf{J(r')}\textrm{dV}' \tag{1}\label{1}\\
- \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}  \int_{V} \big[\bf{r}'\cdot\bf{grad}\big(\frac{1}{r}\big) \big]\bf{J(r')}\textrm{dV}' \\ + \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}  \int_{V} \big[\bf{r}'\cdot\bf{grad}\big[\bf{r}'\cdot\bf{grad}\big(\frac{1}{r}\big) \big]\big]\bf{J(r')}\textrm{dV}'+....
$$
In the above last equation the first term is zero because $\rm{div}\bf{J}=0$, the 2nd term is the standard magnetic moment and is being the product of the current and the enclosed area if the current is filamentary and *planar*, the 3rd term is your first "generalization", i.e., the so-called quadrupole moment, etc. The latter has some practical application but the next higher order moments are usually ignored for being negligible small.

You can also consider the 2nd term $\bf{A}^{(1)}(\bf{r})=- \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}  \int_{V} \big[\bf{r}'\cdot\bf{grad}\big(\frac{1}{r}\big) \big]\bf{J(r')}\textrm{dV}' $ itself as a general definition of the magnet dipole moment valid for arbitrary, not only filamentary or planar currents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is just the standard Multipole expansion though, and it does not answer my question: as stated in the post I already know of a way to calculate the dipole moment through integration but I'm asking if there is a simpler geometric way to derive it.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The multipole expansion you quote does not represent any physical multipole. The terms of the series correspond to "how much the field resembles that created by a $2^n$-pole at the origin". And they're explicitly dependent on the coordinate system. On the other hand, the physical dipole I'm asking about is independent of the reference frame.